# how to add an action to copy/pase or listen to copy event on android

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, copy-paste

Hie!

I'm trying to develop an app that will do one of these 2 options -

1. whenever a user marks a text in any app (using the regular copy/paste), there will be another option besides copy/cut that will open my app. (preferred)
2. My app would listen to a copy text event in another app and will show a notification to the user. when they press it, it will open my app.

I haven't found a way to do either of these options.Some claim that I can listen to the copy activity but I couldn't understand how to do it([Android : How to listen to longclick events in any text area in other applications?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5944541/android-how-to-listen-to-long) click-events-in-any-text-area-in-other-application).

I'm not looking for anyone to write the code for me of course, just a pointer to the right direction if this is possible.

Thanks in advance,
Shahar

Answer (score 0):

After short investigation I don't think it is possible. You may look at [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/text/copy-paste.html) guide, but it says copy/paste is implemented using [ClipboardManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ClipboardManager.html) in Android, which looks like a part of a system. And it doesn't provide any hooks or interfaces to intercept copy/paste events in other app.
Sure you may hack deeper in this mechanismus on rooted device, but this will not work for all users.

Answer (score 0):

Very late response but you can create a custom text selection action, which is an activity with an intent filter with action android.intent.action.PROCESS_TEXT, and whenever a user press on text, a text selection menu appears, your's will be available too,
when the user clicks on your custom text selection action, the activity configures with the android.intent.action.PROCESS_TEXT will be opened for your users.

check this article for implementation steps [Custom text selection action](https://medium.com/@mahmoudwaked/clipboardmanager-does-not-work-on-android-q-smart-solution-3fa2df9cdfa9)